# SQL Most efficient way to delete with 150000 'OR' statements

Tags: mysql

We hold a DB of ~350k email addresses for a client.

They have supplied me with a couple of excel spreadsheets with a combined ~150k email addresses they want to remove (long story short, it was a spammy email list that they had gotten hold of and want to remove the bounce backs).

Using the wonders of find and replace, I have got a query built to perform this huge delete but the query takes too long and times out (no surprise there).

The query I have built is in the form of:

```
DELETE FROM emaillist
WHERE intListID = 68
AND
(strEmailAddress = "aaaa@aaaa.com"
OR strEmailAddress = "aaab@aaaa.com"
OR strEmailAddress = "aaac@aaaa.com"
......
etc etc etc
......
OR strEmailAddress = "zzzy@zzzz.com"
OR strEmailAddress = "zzzz@zzzz.com"
)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: y don't u store this email in a temp table and run the delete query?

Comment: If you can insert them in a table or a temp table, then you can `DELETE` with `JOIN`: `DELETE t1 FROM emaillist INNER JOIN spammyemail AS t2 ON t1.strEmailAddress = t2.emailaddress`

Comment: @MahmoudGamal this should be an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the emails you want to delete in a temporary table. Then you can remove the emails from your original table by using a join

```
DELETE e 
FROM emaillist e
INNER JOIN temp_table t ON t.strEmailAddress = e.strEmailAddress
WHERE intListID = 68
```

After that drop the temp table and your done.

Comment: @Fraser After that, we're interested in your query execution time ;-)

Comment: Running it now. Will report back :)

Comment: Affected rows: 124740 
Time: 70.278ms

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following steps:

1. Load the Excel emails into a "todelete"
2. Build an index on the email field in the "todelete" table
3. Create a new table with the values you want:

   create table newemails as
       select *
       from emaillist
       where not exists (select 1 from todelete where todelete.email = emaillist.email);
4. Truncate emaillist
5. Insert the list back in

The said, you might find that steps (1) and (2) are sufficient, with the query:

```
delete from emaillist
    where not exists (select 1 from todelete where todelete.email = emaillist.email);
```

However, deleting 150,000 rows generates a lot of traffic on the log.  Truncation and re-insertion saves this overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You could import the list in a temporary table and try something like:

```
DELETE FROM emaillist
WHERE intListID = 68
AND strEmailAddress in (Select emailAddress From temporaryTable)
```

An index on strEmailAddress (even created for the duration of the query) could help a lot.